# Python selenium find element by xpath multiple conditions

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xpath

I use python selenium to do web scraping. And Iwould like to catch website with both in a specific date (like [01-20]) and title with specific text in it (like 'public'), how could the code satisfy both ?

I tried the following but no luck

Thank you in advance!!

href:

```
<td width="89%" height="26"> 
<a href="hrefhref" target="_blank" title="sth sth public">sth sth public</a>
</td>
<td width="8%" align="center">[01-20]</td>
<tr>
```

code:

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[title*='public']")
for title in titles:
    links=[title.get_attribute('href') for title in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='[01-20]']/preceding::td[1]/a")]
    urls = [links.get_attribute("href") for links in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[title*='public']")]
    for url in urls:
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
        ###do something
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot see what the problem is, the codes are here

Comment: There is no information about used modules, url, page_source snippet, ... that helps the community to answer - So please improve your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use keyword `and` and `contains` function in xpath:

`'//td[text()="[01-20]"]/preceding::td[1]/a[contains(@title, "资本")]'`

check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTStvDR_jF4) video for more info

EDIT: changed xpath to a working answer

Comment: Thank you so much !but what if title is in another tag as 'a'?

Comment: please, open html of page, then ctrl-F, then use xpath/css selector for experimenting. I can't find any `public` in html

Comment: , website is Chinese character, if possible, please change public to ' 资本'

Comment: you didn't formulate you question clear enough. That's you xpath `//td[text()='[01-20]']/preceding::td[1]/a[contains(@title, "资本")]`. I think it works

Comment: my bad.. wow, that works fine! thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: can you please vote up the answer or make it the best. thanks

Comment: Hello, for this issue, I find it only find title in the first page, how should it jump to the next page if there's no results in the first page?

Comment: because pages have same pattern for every number (e.g. for 5th page `http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code_5.shtml`), create url with needed number ( in `for` loop until you get 404 error or whatever), use `driver.get` with it, and wrap line that searches xpath with `try` block (with exception that is raised when no xpath is found). Or you could get element using `//div[@class="pagination_index"]/a` and then `click()` on it. Also check [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait until element with xpath will appear.